# FastDateFormat HHmmssS behaviour like HHmmSSS

Tags: java, time, apache-commons

The source `FastDateFormat.getInstance("HHmmssS").format(Calendar.getInstance());` returns a string in the format "HHmmssSSS" e.g. 152712599 instead expected 1527125.

The package and version are "package org.apache.commons.lang3.time; @version $Id: FastDateFormat.java 1591488 2014-04-30 21:49:35Z".

A workaround will be provided in the solution below.

Comment: Well, not supported by `FastDateFormat`, but by my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J), example: `System.out.println(ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HHmmssS", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT).format(PlainTime.nowInSystemTime());` // 1633154, and it is also quicker (especially if the formatter is stored as static constant - thread-safe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you want are deciseconds, not milliseconds, but you are right, there is no support for that (yet?).

Beware that formatting it with a single 'S' might give you only the actual millisecond, so you need to use the format string `"HHmmssSSS"`. The substring itself should then be of length `"HHmmssS".length()`.

So your actual workaround/solution should rather be:

```
public static <Format> String HHMMssS(final Format calendar) {
  final String HHmmssS = "HHmmssSSS";
  return FastDateFormat.getInstance(HHmmssS).format(calendar).substring(0, "HHmmssS".length());
}
```

A related question (regarding parsing):
[Deci and Centi Seconds parsing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558663/deci-and-centi-seconds-parsing-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround cuts off the last 2 digits of 'HHmmssSSS'.

```
public static <Format> String HHMMssS(final Format calendar)
{
    final String HHmmssS = "HHmmssS";
    return FastDateFormat.getInstance(HHmmssS).format(calendar).substring(0, HHmmssS.length());
}
```